# DELL Server won't accept Corsair RAM

Tags: memory, dell

I've ordered DELL PowerEdge™ T110 II with 2GB RAM and

Corsair 16GB 1600MHz CL10 DDR3 Vengeance Memory Kit(2 X 8GB). By some reason the server works only with the original memory and won't accept the Corsair's one. Just before returning the memory could anyone advice on:

a. Any tips for installing RAM (I've four slots - white black white black, my initial attempt was to use slots 1 & 3 or 2 & 4 - neither worked, then a single chip which didn't work neither). while failing 2 uses slots give red on signal indicator (the one with the curve) with 3 & 4 lights on, while 1 & 3 gives blue indicator with the same lights on.

b. Are there any general suitability rules I've got missed? - i.e. what could make a memory kit unsuitable for a server?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd suggest that the server requires ECC memory and the memory you've got probably isn't ECC. I'd always suggest buying memory from a vendor that sells you memory matched to the specific model of server (for example, crucial's website).

Comment: I have run into Dell servers rejecting memory because they needed a BIOS update.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your server requires ECC memory as do most servers.
Return the kit if you can and get supported dimms.
Please consult your servers manual before buying / installing RAM.

see page 73 of the owners manual

ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-t110-2_Owner%27s%20Manual_en-us.pdf

Comment: I'd thought ECC support is a useful extra (as per the link you posted) but not a requirement, could you confirm if it's a requirement? Also what level of ECC support do I need?

Comment: I updated my answer with the actual location of the information.

Comment: ECC boards require ECC RAM. As a rule of thumb nearly all server mobos require ECC RAM

Comment: You also have to check if the ram vs requirements is "buffered" (registered) or "unbuffered" "unregistered" (as in the T110 II) !